# Why do my css icons disappear when I scroll down on a phone?

Tags: html, css

So I have a navbar and it looks like this:

[image]

Styles:

```
.nav_bar{
    height:100vh;
    width: 75px;
    background-color:#2e2e2e;
    z-index: 9;

    @include media(tablet, mobile){
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 65px;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    &__links{
        position: relative;
        @include flex(center, flex-start);
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap:40px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

`navbar__links` is a class for icons. So I tried making it responsive and it looks like this:
[image]

It looks alright, but when I scroll down on a phone the icons just disappear
[image]

I can't figure out the problem, does it have to do with `position: fixed` or `z-index` but I want my icons to stay where they are when I scroll down on a phone

Edit:

A working example:

Link to my vercel app:
[vercel app](https://messenger-jrh6r0i3f-loveroftherussianqueen.vercel.app/)

You can enter with login: `tyler@mail.com`, password: `ssssss`

Comment: Please provide working example.

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela hi! i added a working example link

Comment: Did you fix it; I just tried your example with Chrome mobile simulator and I can't scroll down cause of the  overflow: hidden. When I changed hidden to scroll though, the icons wouldn't disappear when scrolling down.

Comment: @Thanos hi! may i ask where exactly did you change `overflow: hidden`? i have `overflow-y: auto` in `Home.jsx` component

Comment: @Carl I saw the `overflow-y: auto` but I think it gets overridden with `overflow: hidden` in class `.users_container`.

Comment: @Thanos thanks, i'll fix it and check if it solves my problem, i'll inform later :)

Comment: Could you post a video or gif to show how the bug acts?

Comment: @Huckc sure, how could i post a video on stackoverflow?